# Unrecognized selector crash

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, unrecognized-selector

I have a modal VC and a close button, whenever I hit the close button I get this error

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DynatraceSessionReplay.ProxyDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282e9edc0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'd only like to dismiss my current modal VC, but I keep getting that crash.

Here's what my close function looks like. I have no idea what is going on? Can anyone please help me out? Many thanks in advance!

```
@IBAction func onClose(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Closing! \(#function)")
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        print("Dismissed!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing and reconnecting the `@IBAction` to the `ViewController`?

Comment: Yeah I did that already, but the same thing keeps happening ):

Comment: Are you sure it's related to this `onClose` method? In the error message, it refers to `scrollViewDidScroll`.